# How can I made a data encryption method? (SHA256, Base64, etc.)

Tags: encryption, base64

I would love to make my own data encryption method like Base64 and such. (preferably in Python.)
Would it be secure if I assigned "a" to for say a random number between 1-100 and a random letter or such. (for example 53f) and other letters are combinations and its random. But then how would I make a decoder, sorry for the long question haha. Thanks!

Comment: first learn some basics. Base64 is not encryption with the goal to keep something secret but just an encoding algorithm. Everyone can decode a base64 string. SHA256 is a hashing algortihm which can't be reversed, also not useable to transfer secret information. What you're talking about sounds like 'Vigenere Cipher'. Google for that to find out more.

Comment: @jps Alright will do thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not start by making your own encryption method.  Start by reading Bruce Schneier's [Memo to the Amateur Cipher Designer](https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram/archives/1998/1015.html#cipherdesign).

Then write your own versions of the simpler existing ciphers: Caesar, Vigenere, (both of historical interest) RC4, Feistel.  That will help you with the structure of ciphers, particularly RC4 -- a stream cipher and Feistel -- a block cipher framework.

Base64 is not a cipher, as has been pointed out.  It is a useful exercise to write your own Base64 encoder/decoder, though most modern languages include one in their library anyway.  That exercise helps you practice bit manipulations.

When you have done all that, find an implementation of AES that you are happy using.  Any cipher you devise will not be as secure as AES.